# Reload number of sections in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a "settings" view controller which essentially allows the user to change how many sections there are in the UITableView in a different view controller. How can I implement a change that when the settings view controller is unwound the tableview is reloaded to have the new number of sections without removing the data in the sections which will remain?

EDIT:

I've tried calling tableView.reloadData() when it is segued back into the main view controller, but this doesn't add the new sections.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any examples of code?

Comment: _"without removing the data in the sections which will remain"_. You would have stored this information in your data source. So, just keep the relevant data in your data source and update only the ones that need to be updated and then update your table.

Comment: What do you mean by _when the settings view controller is unwound_ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I implement a change that when the settings view controller is unwound the tableview is reloaded to have the new number of sections...

Call `reloadData()` or `reloadSections(_:with:)`. Either of those should cause the table to ask its data source for the number of sections.

> ...to have the new number of sections without removing the data in the sections which will remain?

There's not much sense in reloading the sections of a table but trying to hold onto the existing cells. Just figuring out which ones are still valid and which ones aren't would add a lot of complexity to `UITableView`'s interface without much benefit.

Remember that the *data* isn't really *in* a table view at all — the data should be in your model and made accessible to the table through the table's data source. The table only cares about its cells — it doesn't know anything about the data each cell displays.

> I've tried calling tableView.reloadData() when it is segued back into the main view controller, but this doesn't add the new sections.

It sounds like the table's data source isn't getting the message that the number of sections has changed. Try putting a breakpoint in your `numberOfSections(in:)` method and so that you can look at the number of sections that the data source is telling the table it should have.

Comment: Thank you. reloadData() is exactly what I needed. I just had an irrelevant problem in my code.